# Homology of simplicial manifolds

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $M_{\bullet}$ be a simplicial manifold. There are two ways to computing its cohomology. Consider the cosimplicial module $A_{DR}(M)$. It defines a functor $A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})\: : \: \boldsymbol{\Delta}\to dgMod$. Let $\Omega\: : \: \boldsymbol{\Delta}^{op}\to dgMod$ be the functor that associate to $[n]$ the dg module of polynomial differential forms over the geometric $n$-simplex (it is a manifold with corners). We consider the bifunctor $A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})\times \Omega\: : \: \boldsymbol{\Delta}\times \boldsymbol{\Delta}^{op}\to dgMod$. We denote with $Tot_{1}(A_{DR}(M_{\bullet}))$ be the end of $A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})\times \Omega$. On the other hand we denote with $Tot_{2}(A_{DR}(M_{\bullet}))$ the normalized complex associated to the cosimplicial differential module $A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})$. It is well-know (see for example Johan Louis Dupont, Simplicial de Rham Cohomology and characteristic classes of flat bundles Topology 15 (1976)) that 
$$
H^{*}(Tot_{2}(A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})) )\cong H^{*}(Tot_{1}(A_{DR}(M_{\bullet})) )
$$
and that the cohomology coincide with the cohomology of the fat realization of $M_{\bullet}$. My questions are:

1) Is there a dual version of that? In order to get $Tot_{2}$ my guess was replace $A_{DR}^{*}$ with the chains complex functor $C_{\bullet}$ and then take the normalized total complex. Some suggestion for $Tot_{1}$?

2) Is there some relation between the homology of the (fat?) geometric realization of $M_{\bullet}$ and the homology of the two obtained complexes?